# Somar resultado da coluna PONTOS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde!

Tenho a seguinte situação: tenho uma tabela com os resultados de alguns jogos de futebol. Consegui montar um SELECT e atribuir 3 pontos para quem venceu e 1 pontos para os empates. Agora preciso somar todos os pontos de cada time e montar uma tabela do primeiro ao ultimo colocado. O que não estou conseguindo fazer e essa soma de pontos. Segue o SELECT que fiz até o momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT CDJOGO, CDEQUIPE, NMABREVIADO, CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA,

CASE 
    WHEN CDEQUIPE = CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA THEN +3
    WHEN CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA IS NULL THEN  +1
END AS PONTOS

FROM EQUIPE AS E
JOIN JOGO AS J ON E.CDEQUIPE = J.CDEQUIPECASA OR E.CDEQUIPE = J.CDEQUIPEVISITANTE
GROUP BY CDJOGO, CDEQUIPE, NMABREVIADO, CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA
```

Comment: Edite a sua questão e coloque a estrutura das tabelas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Será que desta forma teria o resultado que pergunta?

```
SELECT CDEQUIPE, NMABREVIADO, PONTOS = sum(PONTOS)
FROM
(
SELECT CDJOGO, CDEQUIPE, NMABREVIADO, CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA,

CASE 
    WHEN CDEQUIPE = CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA THEN +3
    WHEN CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA IS NULL THEN  +1
END AS PONTOS

FROM EQUIPE AS E
JOIN JOGO AS J ON E.CDEQUIPE = J.CDEQUIPECASA OR E.CDEQUIPE = J.CDEQUIPEVISITANTE
GROUP BY CDJOGO, CDEQUIPE, NMABREVIADO, CDEQUIPEVENCEDORA
)
GROUP BY CDEQUIPE, NMABREVIADO
ORDER BY PONTOS DESC
```